# Prove the following relation in vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $(V,+, \cdot)$ be a $\mathbb{K}$ -vector space. Prove the following relations.

1. $\mathrm{o} \cdot x=\mathrm{o},$ for all $x \in V$
2. $\lambda \cdot \mathrm{o}=\mathrm{o},$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$.
3. $(-1) \cdot x=-x$ for all $x \in V$.

---

Here is my idea, if it has some problems or you have to add for me please kindly share an idea for me.

Since $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a $\mathbb{K}$ -vector space.

1. $\exists \mathrm{o}=0 \in\mathbb{K}$ for all $x\in V$
   $$\mathrm{o}x=0x=0=\mathrm{o}$$
2. $\exists \lambda\in\mathbb{K}, \lambda\cdot\mathrm{o}=\lambda \cdot 0=0=\mathrm{o}$
3. Since $-x\in V$ such that $(-1)\cdot x=1\cdot(-x)$

---

Please kindly share or recommend me. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, Note that $0.x = (0 + 0).x = 0.x + 0.x$. So $0.x = 0$ for all $x$. About the second equality, use $\lambda.0 = \lambda.(0 + 0) = \lambda.0 + \lambda.0$ to show that $\lambda.0 = 0$ for all $\lambda$. And in order to prove the last one, Note that:
$$(-1).x + x = ((-1) + 1).x = 0.x = 0 $$. Since the additive inverse of every vector is unique, It follows that $(-1).x = -x$ for all $x$.